# How can I get the size of an autosized WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, size, actualwidth

I have a Window that is autosized around it's content. For an animation I'd need it's width and height. `ActualWidth` is always the max width of the window, `Width` and `Height` properties say NaN.

Answer (score 2):

[ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx)/[ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) will give you the actual sizes of the window - given by the layout system, which is based on the actual rendering of the window. These should be the sizes you are looking for. However, there might be a slight delay in the calculation as it is based on rendering, so if they are wrong I guess they aren't calculated yet - and you got a race condition going on.. You can read more about this in links above, where there are some important notes on when the actual sizes are calculated - and hence - why they can be delayed.

[Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx)/[Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx) are requested sizes, and if not set explicitly they will hold their default values, which is Double.NaN.

Comment: I need the size of the window before it's rendered, the animation is kind of fade in combined with scaling, which needs to be centered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Window's [UpdateLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx)-Method to have `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` validated.

Comment: Made my day. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible you should use a `ScaleTransform` instead of changing `Height` and `Width` values when animating a size change. Not only can it help with performance, but it also gets around issues like this since instead of setting a specific size value which you may not know, the scale values are specified as percentages.

Comment: I need to center the ScaleTransform. I don't change Height and Width, they are only changed by autosizing and scaling